# Next 13 with Mongoose is not working in server component

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, react-server-components

I just updated the next version to 13 in a project to test out the `app` dir.

I have a function called `getData()` :

```
export const getData = async () => {
    await dbConnect()
    return await DataModel.find()
}
```

My `dbConnect()` function is a generic function that uses the cached connection if it is cached, or connects to mongodb if it isn't connected.

My server component, inside `app/page.tsx`

```
export const page = async () => {
    const data = await getData() // <-- Gets stuck here
}
```

I have tried using `dbConnect()` inside the server component aswell, but the same problem occurs.

If I add an API route that runs `getData()` and use my server component like this:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    return await fetch('/api/data')
}

export const page = async () => {
    const data = await fetchData() // <-- Works if I call internal API
}
```

However, calling your own API seems redundant and might worsen performance. I also loose TS return type from the `getData()` function.

Comment: New find - It has something to do with the connection to the database. I have made some testing and you can get the data in a server component if it's the first thing you do. For example if I restart my server and call `find()` in a server component it works the first time. But then it dies.